# Python: multi-line text file reading as single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to read in a text file containing words separated by new lines. However, I can't seem to get PyCharm to recognise the linebreaks. I've tried everything, including [changing the Line Separator settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html), but it still treats the text file as a single line. Any solutions?

```
inFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
wordList = []
for line in inFile:
    wordList.append(line.strip().lower())
len(wordList) # returns 1
```

```
inFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
inFile.readlines() # returns 1 line containing all words
```

Text file: https://courses.edx.org/assets/courseware/v1/1e89542cc136bc1e496aac7130cac1ba/asset-v1:MITx+6.00.1x+2T2018+type@asset+block/ProblemSet4.zip

IDE: PyCharm 2018.2.4 on macOS

Thanks

Comment: Python interpreter runs this fine on my end.

Comment: `'AIRTIME\n', 'AIRTIMES\n'` ..This is the output of your code. Each word is on a new line. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Must be something wrong with my IDE/interpreter as my output comes through as a list of length 1...

wordList
['a i ad am an as at ax be by do em en ex go he hi ho if in is it me my no ... ']


Anyway I tried the alternate method posted and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this:

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
     words = file.read().split()

print(words)
```

and you will get:

```
['AA', 'AAH', 'AAHED', 'AAHING', ......]
```

If want all words in one huge string, just avoid the `split()` method:

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
         words = file.read()
```